# Is bad form to answer a question that would probably be closed for lack of context?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, new-users

Sometimes I see a question from a new user, the sort of question that's followed by a "What have you tried?" comment. I suspect that if it were flagged, it would be closed.

Is it considered to be bad form to post a full solution to these questions?

Comment: Related discussion here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/can-i-try-to-tell-experienced-users-not-to-answer-bad-questions

Comment: There are too many variables to deem it bad form in all cases, but it's safe to say that it is premature. Coaxing more context and dialogue out of the asker before answering would probably benefit the asker and the solution both. Maybe you will learn something along the way that helps you decide if the complete answer would be bad to give.

Comment: Sometimes I want to provide an answer for the sport of it. Then I think a hint is what's needed to help the asker. Then someone will go and lay out a full response. The challenge is to avoid the sense of competition.

Comment: Some such solutions may be downvoted by those who think it is bad form.

Comment: If you think it is an interesting problem, I would encourage you to answer and edit the Question (body and title) to make it sensible to other Readers.  There are so many posts that you can be selective in responding to Questions which you will find rewarding.

Comment: I think it is bad form.  And yes, I frequently downvote answers to questions that should obviously be closed, especially full solutions given to homework style questions that are asked with zero context.

Comment: Most of these posts are from people who genuinely do not understand what is in the question and are just looking for help. I believe it is bad form to give a full solution to any "homework problem", no matter what the user has provided. But often I can make a good guess as to what their problem might be, and give hints that I hope will push them in the right direction to answer it themselves. And also hopefully help them in developing an understanding of the problem. If so, then I do not believe it is bad form to offer the hint, even if the user has provided no feedback.

Comment: I find it in even worse form when those who furnish complete and detailed answers to homework questions without any regard to site policy, and have those answers downvoted by the community, then have the audacity to post comments requesting that the asker of the question to supply their own thoughts *after the fact* in order for the question to not be closed.  Such people also appear to have no ethical problem with calling the downvoting "politically motivated."